# Using mod to print multiple characters per line in Java

Tags: java, modulo

If this is too broad, I can try and rephrase my question. I'm just simply wanting to know exactly how mod prints x number of characters per line. My textbook does not explain this, and I keep finding this during searches online. For example, if someone wants 10 characters per line, I've seen i % 10 == 0. How does this work if mod is used to find remainders?

Answer (score 0):

In a loop that increases your i variable for each character, whenever you have i % 10 == 0, that means that you have a multiple of 10... so, it's time to go to a new line.
To understand, just try this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " - " + (i % 10));
}
```